# Обратный Iterator для LinkedList

Tags: c++

Сам обратный Iterator работает, но уходит в бесконечность, как это можно поправить?

main.cpp

```
LinkedList<int> A;
for (int i = 1; i < 10; ++i)
{
    A.Add(i * 10);
}
LinkedList<int>::reverse_iterator rp;
rp = A.rbegin();

while (rp != A.rend())
{
    ++rp;
    std::cout << *rp << std::endl;

}
```

fuction.cpp

```
LinkedReverseListIterator & operator ++()//Pref.form

{
    typename LinkedList<T>::Elem<T> *item  = list->head;

    while (item->next != this->curItem)
    {
        item = item->next;
        if (item->next == NULL || item->next == this->curItem)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    curItem = item;
    return *this;
}
```

LinkedReversIteratorList.h

```
#pragma once
#include "LinkedList.h"



template<class T>
class LinkedReverseListIterator
{
private:
    LinkedList<T> *list;//указатель на список, по которому будет перемещаться указатель
    typename LinkedList<T>::Elem<T> *curItem;//Elem<T> - указатель на текущий элемент в списке, нао который указывает итератор
public:
    LinkedReverseListIterator()
    {
        this->list = NULL;
        this->curItem = NULL;
    }
    LinkedReverseListIterator(LinkedList<T> *list, typename LinkedList<T>::Elem<T> *item)
    {
        this->list = list;
        this->curItem = item;
    }

    bool operator ==(LinkedReverseListIterator<T> &p)
    {
        return (this->list == p.list) && (this->curItem == p.curItem);
    }

    bool operator !=(LinkedReverseListIterator<T> &p)
    {
        return !(*this == p);
    }
    T & operator *()
    {
        return this->curItem->value;
    }
    LinkedReverseListIterator & operator ++()//Pref.form
    {
        typename LinkedList<T>::Elem<T> *item  = list->head;

        while (item->next != this->curItem)
        {
            item = item->next;
            if (item->next == NULL || item->next == this->curItem)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        curItem = item;
        return *this;
    }
    /*LinkedReverseListIterator operator ++(int z)//Postf.form
    {
        LinkedReverseListIterator<T> tmp = *this;//copy ctor is not nesessary
        if (this->curItem != NULL)
        {
            this->curItem = this->curItem->next;
        }
        return tmp;
    }*/

};
```

Comment: Ваши записи какие то хаотические, непонятные ни вам, ни кому либо и ни компилятору.  Для профилактики: обратные итераторы инкрементируются от конца , а декрементируются к концу...

Comment: Не я придумавал, задание от предподователя: написать обратный итератор LinkedList., сейчас прикрепляю полный файл, проект очень огромный что бы его сюда вылаживать, сжал как можно лаконичнее

Comment: Метод работает нормально, тоесть доходит до конца item и присваивает значение this->curItem, и так до начала списка, но вместо выхода, он идет опять в конец присваивает значение this->curItem и так до бесконечности...

Comment: Скорее всего, если список должен поддерживать обратный итератор, то это двусвязный список. В коллекциях не принято реализовывать итераторы, которые не могут работать эффективно. Ещё чит, для удобства можно сделать кольцевой список, в котором всегда есть служебный нулевой элемент. еnd() и rend() внутри хранят ссылку на него. Только нужно value хранить или как указатель (std::unique_ptr идеально подходит), или поиграться с наследованием.

Comment: По условиям задачи было не реализовать двусвязный список, а реализовать в односвязном списке обратный итератор, принцип не в эфективности кода, а просто, что бы это реализовать. Условие такое.